# Android: gradle build stops due to not being able to resolve the symbols

Tags: android, gradle, android-appcompat

I am currently using Android Studio, and I added three libraries (`com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1`, `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1` and `com.android.support:support-v13:23.0.1`) at File -> Project structures -> Modules -> app -> Dependencies -> Library dependency.

Also, I checked out the build.gradle file and it didn't seem to have a problem. Here's the gradle code.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.marshall.thequizshow"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':volley')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.0.1'
}
```

But still, when I try to run the app, I cannot go any further because the gradle build messages keep saying things like 'Error retrieving parent for item'. Here's one of the messages.

```
/Users/marshall/AndroidStudioProjects/TheQuizShow/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/23.0.1/res/values-hdpi/values-hdpi.xml
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Base.Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle.Common'.
Error:(6, 23) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'barLength'.
Error:(8, 23) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'drawableSize'.
Error:(7, 23) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'gapBetweenBars'.
```

I clearly added the libraries into my projects but I still do not understand why it keeps saying that it cannot resolve the library-related symbols..

Comment: do you have the library installed to begin with?

Comment: Can you also post your XML, where the error occurs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I somehow found the answer on this matter, but I still don't know why it occurred. Anyways, I simply solved this issue by cleaning and re-building the project..